# MissingComponentException: There is no 'SpriteRenderer' attached to the "Balletjes(Clone)" game object, but a script is trying to access it

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I get this error:

> "MissingComponentException: There is no 'SpriteRenderer' attached to the "Balletjes(Clone)" game object, but a script is trying to access it."

[image: Screen capture Inventory]

I would like to assign the name of a sprite to the variable `goldCoinPopUp`. I searched a lot but nothing worked. Can anyone help me please?

**ItemDragHandler**

```c#
public class ItemDragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{

    public GameObject prefab;

    Vector2 original;

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100);
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out hit, 100)) 
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Terrain") 
            {
                transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab,hit.point, Quaternion.EulerAngles(0f, 3f, 0f)); // 3d object
                obj.AddComponent<GenerateResources>(); // link to GenerateResources script
                Vector3 img = new Vector3(0, 8.66f, 0);
                obj.transform.position += img;
            } 
            else 
            {
                transform.localPosition = original;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            transform.localPosition = original;
        }
    }

    void Start () 
    {
        original = transform.localPosition;
    }
}
```

**GenerateResources**

```c#
public class GenerateRessources : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private int ressourcesInBuilding;

    public int valueWhenCollect = 10;

    private float timerExtraRessource;

    public float generateRate = 4;

    public SpriteRenderer goldCoinPopUp;

    private GameObject currentGameObject;

    private GameObject Inventory;

    void Start () 
    {
        goldCoinPopUp = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        goldCoinPopUp.enabled = false;
        currentGameObject = gameObject.GetComponent<GameObject>();
        Inventory = GameObject.Find("Inventory");
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        AddResource();
        getResources();
    }

    private void AddResource()
    {
        timerExtraRessource += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timerExtraRessource >= generateRate)
        {
            ressourcesInBuilding++;
            timerExtraRessource = 0;
            if (ressourcesInBuilding >= valueWhenCollect)
            {
                goldCoinPopUp.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void getResources() 
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                RaycastHit hit;
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f))
                {
                    if (hit.transform.gameObject != null)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f))
            {
                if (hit.transform.gameObject != currentGameObject)
                {
                    if (goldCoinPopUp.enabled == true)
                    {
                        goldCoinPopUp.enabled = false;
                        Inventory.GetComponent<GameController>().Gold += ressourcesInBuilding;
                        ressourcesInBuilding = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code depends on SpriteRenderer being present, while your prefab does not have one. You can work around this problem by adding the following attribute before your class definiton

```c#
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
public class GenerateRessources : MonoBehaviour
```

However the automatically added SpriteRenderer will have no sprite attached, hence a better solution would be to make sure your prefab does indeed have a reasonable sprite attached

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: Note that the [`[RequireComponent]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html) tag only has an effect if the `GenerateRessources` is newly added to a GameObject. If `GenerateRessources` already is on a GameObject adding the tag afterwards does **not** add the component automatically. From the docu: `Note that RequireComponent only checks for missing dependencies during the moment the component is added to a GameObject. Existing instances of the component whose GameObject lacks the new dependencies will not have those dependencies automatically added.`

Comment: @derHugo please note that the component in question is indeed added in runtime according to the code posted

Comment: @Aricia open your prefab in the editor (add it to the scene if needed), add the componen, and save the prefab